# Synchronizing MS SQL databases using custom TCP protocol

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

Currently I have a TCP server setup have Custom TCP protocol used to receive and send data from different clients across the globe to the central server.

Now I have a new requirement each of the client locations will have SQL database installed and data has to be synchronized with Central SQL server.Now I am trying to use Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize the data between the server and clients.I would like to leverage TCP message already developed.Can provide any inputs how to use Custom TCP transport protocol for data synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

If you lookup the N-Tier samples using WCF, you can change the WCF transport. Not sure if you're custom transport will work with WCF though. But it's a good start to look at how to use the Sync provider proxy.